# PowerShell Unable to Parse Large Floats?

Tags: powershell, parsing

**EDIT: The error was caused by use of a backslash instead of a backtick.**

Provided are the ps1 file and a small sample (tsv) data file. I've gone through various examples of parsing float/double/decimal types, but for some reason, PowerShell seems to fail above a certain digit count. Is there a way around this?

Script:

```
$allData = @()
$sysStats = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
$count = 0

ForEach($line in Get-Content "SystemStats.tsv")
{
    if(-not $line.Contains("PDH"))
    {
        $line = $line -replace'[""]',""
        $entries = $line.split("`t")


        $entries[0]
        $entries[1]
        $entries[2]
        $entries[3]



        $sysStats[0] = $sysStats[0] + $entries[1]
        $sysStats[1] = [decimal] $entries[2]
        $sysStats[2] = [float] $entries[3]

        [float]$entries[1]
        [double]$entries[2]
        [decimal]$entries[3]

        $count = $count + 1
    }
}



$sysStats[0] = $sysStats[0] / $count
$sysStats[1] = $sysStats[1] / $count
$sysStats[2] = $sysStats[2] / $count

$count
$sysStats[0]
$sysStats[1]
$sysStats[2]
```

Data File:

```
"(PDH-TSV 4.0) (E. Australia Standard Time)(-600)"  "\\VAWSHRADDEV4001\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Time"  "\\VAWSHRADDEV4001\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use" "\\VAWSHRADDEV4001\Network Interface(AWS PV Network Device _0)\Bytes Total/sec"
"12/05/2016 13:02:43.962"   " " "24.549028983000845"    " "
"12/05/2016 13:02:53.976"   "11.686062679123754"    "24.678379230714455"    "7363.3148341056431"
```

Output:

```
12/05/2016 13:02:43.962     24.549028983000845   
0
0
0
12/05/2016 13:02:53.976 11.686062679123754  24.678379230714455  7363.3148341056431
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
```

Comment: Problem seems to be that your tabs are not actual tabs - your tsv has the entries separated by 3 or more spaces, not tabs

Comment: I've run the file through a Java program using String.split("\t"), and that worked just fine, so that's not the issue. And, as you can see by the printout, the string gets split using "\t" in PS just fine too. It's the parsing to floats/doubles/decimals that fails.

Comment: If your file truly has tabs, the correct way would be to use ``$line.Split("`t")``. PowerShell uses backticks rather than backslash as an escape character

Comment: Edit: NVM, apostrophe vs. backtick, and somehow now it works fine. Sigh... It's always the tiny mistakes. Thank you!